# vbulletin vB_XHTML_Ready is not defined

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy trabajando con **`vbulletin`** y **`nodejs`** pero recibo el siguiente error:

> vbulletin-postbit.js?v=423:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: vB_XHTML_Ready
>   is not defined

he buscado y no encuentro mucho acerca de esto, podría alguien ayudarme?

Comment: El error te dice que `vB_XHTML_Ready` no esta definido puedes que no tengas agregado esa propiedad o no este inicializada,pero seria mas facil si subes el codigo donde te aparece el error , para poder saber un poco mas de tu error, y cambia el nombre de la pregunta, puede que recibas puntuaciones negativas

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español, te sugiero que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y así editar tu pregunta para que sea mucho mejor, aparte a eso te invito a que hagas el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que ganes tu primera [medalla!](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)